# How to prevent a password-locking denial of service for a Windows Service Account

Tags: active-directory

For a fairly standard, internal facing, web app of an IIS layer talking to an MS SQL back end, we are using a service account for the IIS to talk to SQL.

We also have in our Active Directory setup a password lockout set, so that too many guesses lock the account.

Following on from [Is account lockout a denial of service attack waiting to happen?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7235/is-account-lockout-a-denial-of-service-attack-waiting-to-happen) scenario - does setting the Deny Logon Locally for the service account user impact this lockout feature in any way?

Alternatively (additionally?) is this the kind of scenario that [Managed Service Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560633%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) are supposed to help fix?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's precisely what MSAs are designed to guard against, but they certainly do, and it's best practice to use them when you do need a non-interactive account as a service account.

The Deny Logon Locally flag has no effect on locokout policy - authentication happens before those policies are enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Well as per me i think this is the issues you are facing,
[image]

To secure the Managed service accounts please refer to this link,

http://hitachi-id.com/password-manager/docs/password-management-best-practices.html

Hope this help if this is the secenario.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, you can also configure exactly what machines the account is allowed to be used on.  I'm pretty sure this will prevent the authentication process even starting.

I can't remember if this is exposed through ADUC, but it's ultimately defined in the userWorkstations attribute of the user's object in AD.